# Create an App Extension/DLC for a Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

The title pretty much explains it.

I am developing a flutter app and I want to create some sort of way in which I can call functions from another app to achieve a sort of 'Extension/DLC' effect. How can I achieve this in Flutter.